# How to use IOptions<T> as a generic parameter in a generic method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to create a generic method that use `IOptions<T>` as parameter but the code seems to be invalid.

Visual studio displays the following message:

> TConfig must be a non-abstract type with a non-parameterless
>   constructor in order to use it as a parameter 'TOption' in the generic
>   type or method `'IOptions<TOptions>'`

Any suggestion on how to fix this would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
public static IServiceCollection AddConfigurations<TConfig>(
    this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, 
    IOptions<TConfig> options) 
    where TConfig : class
{
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is, that [`IOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.options.ioptions-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) has the following contraint:

```
where TOptions : class, new()
```

So you need this constraint (`new()`) too:

```
public static IServiceCollection AddConfigurations<TConfig>(
    this IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration configuration, 
    IOptions<TConfig> options) 
    where TConfig : class, new()
{
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at the constraints on `T` in the definition of `IOptions<T>`. The constraints on `AddConfigurations<TConfig>` need to have at least those restrictions on `TConfig` since it uses `IOptions<TConfig>`.